# R: How to stop a for statement when a if condition is met

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement, time-series

I have a time series of prices and I am trying to create a trading strategy. I need to stop the trade as soon as the *price_cap* is met. I have data stored in a database and I need to create a list that indicates all the long positions (list called *long*). I have tried the following, but even if the condition is met, the list continues to store value:

```
long = list()
for (i in 5:length(index)) {

  long[i] = data$target_price[i]
  
    if (data$target_price > price_cap){
    
      break
    
    }
  
  print(long)
  
}
```

Any idea?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Your `if` condition is checking the whole column and `if` is not vectorized.  Did you meant `if(data$target_price[i]> price_cap)`

Comment: Absolutely, that was a stupid error. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` is not a vectorized function.  It expects an input logical expression with a length of 1.  So, inside the loop, we need the `data$price[i]` instead of the whole column

```
for(i in seq_len(nrow(data))) {
    long[[i]] <- data$target_price[i]
    if(data$target_price[i] > price_cap) {
       break
     }
   }
long
```

#### data

```
long <- list()
data <- data.frame(target_price = c(5, 10, 5, 20))
price_cap <- 6
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65754821/12158757) already pointed out the issue and showed a clear way to fix it.

Below is another implementation for your objective

```
long <- with(data, as.list(target_price[seq(min(which(target_price > price_cap)) + 1)]))
```

which gives

```
> long
[[1]]
[1] 5

[[2]]
[1] 10
```